# Can't access this.state in other function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, jsx

```
class Uploader extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          data: '',
          name:'',
          loading: false
        }
    }
}
```

This is the function where I load value in this.state.load

```
 onChange(e) {
    let files = e.target.files;
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    this.state.name = files[0].name;

    reader.onload = ((e) => {
        console.log("file is",e.target.result);
        const formData = {data: e.target.result};
        this.state.data = formData;
        this.setState({data: this.state.data});
        console.log(this.state.data); // here it gives value whats inside file
    });
    this.setState({'name': this.state.name});
    console.log(this.state.data)  // here it doesn't print anything
}
```

calling it in any function:

```
onUpload() {
    console.log(this.state.data);
}
```

It doesn't render. It gives: "error state undefined".
How can I use this.state.data in other functions or other scopes of code, any other way to call this value or need of this correction ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making a function (except arrow function) creates it's own instance of `this`. 
So there's no state object inside your function. To deal with this problem you have two ways -

**Use an arrow function** -

using an arrow function does not create it's own instance of `this`

```
 onUpload = () => {
    console.log(this.state.data) 
}
```

**Bind your function's `this` to class's `this`**

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props)
  this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  this.onUpload = this.onUpload.bind(this);
}
```

Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: binding does work, as per standards of code its necessary

Answer (score 1):

Use bind in constructor:

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props)
  this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}
```

Or use arrow function:

```
onChange = (e) => {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind your method with the class, otherwise `this` will be `undefined`

  1.

```
class Uploader extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          data: '',
          name :'',
          loading : false
        }

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }
}
```

Or use arrow function in class properties if you have support for it.

2. ```
   class Uploader extends React.Component {

       constructor(props) {
           super(props);
           this.state = {
             data: '',
             name :'',
             loading : false
           }
       }

       onChange = () => {}
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Imran for your answer, my code worked with binding and  '**onUpload = () => {**'

Comment: though it was also a correct format and my code needed these changes too !

Answer (score 0):

change you function to this:

```
onChange(e){
    const that = this ; // add this
    let files = e.target.files;
    let reader =new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    // don't set directly value to state !
    // this.state.name = files[0].name;
    this.setState({name: files[0].name}, function() {
       console.log(that.state.name)  // here it doesn't print anything
    });

    reader.onload = ((e) => {
        console.log("file is",e.target.result);
        //const formData = { data : e.target.result }
        //this.state.data = formData; 
        // Use setState callback to get state result 
        that.setState({data : e.target.result}, function() {
          console.log(that.state.data) // here it gives value whats inside file
        });

    });


}
```

Comment: thanks @BaBak for the right coding standards of writing **that.setState({data : e.target.result}, function() {
          console.log(that.state.data) // here it gives value whats inside file
        });** i used these standards.